# Does the Earth receive a net charge from the aurorae?

Tags: geophysics, solar-terrestrial-physics, electromagnetism, auroras

The sun radiates a lot of charged particles to the Earth. When the magnetic field of the Earth lines up to the poles, we get the beautiful polar lights.

But are there as many negative charged as positive charged particles or vice versa, such that the Earth gets charged by the Sun?

Comment: You will want to change "polar lights" in the title to "aurorae".

Comment: Seems like there are two questions here...

Comment: I think this is the wrong question to ask. Instead, maybe we could ask if the Earth receives a net charge _differential  between the poles_ -- do positively-charged particles prefer one pole and negatively charged poles the other?

Answer (score 3):

No. If that were the case, the Sun would eventually develop a net charge. Let's imagine that's the case and the Sun develops a net  positive charge. That charge would eventually stop negative particles from flying away and facilitate the ejection of positive ones. This regime would then restore the neutral charge of the Sun.
This negative feedback makes sure the Sun remains neutral and that Solar winds carry no net charge.

See this Q&A for more details:[Does the solar wind correspond to a net electrical current?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257418/does-the-solar-wind-correspond-to-a-net-electrical-current)

Comment: related and "currently" unanswered (no pun intended): [What are the experimental limits to the residual charge of the Sun?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23319/7982)